# Excel Transpose Certain JSON Fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, json, power-query

I'm pulling data into Excel via a webhook (JSON). It appears in Power Query Editor like this:

```
| name   |  groupName |  key   | value |
| host1  |   group1   |  tag1  | val1  |
| host1  |   group1   |  tag2  |       |
| host1  |   group1   |  tag3  | val3  |
```

How do I transpose the key + value columns to be represented like this:

```
| name   | groupName  | tag1   | tag2 | tag3 |
| host1  |  group1    | val1   |      | val3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

Select Columns **key** and **value**- go to **Transform**- Select **Pivot Column**:

[image]